# Passing JSON from Rails 2 to Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

When Backbone.js gets JSON from the server, it expects it to *not* have the
model-name wrapper that Rails/ActiveRecord applies via the to_json call. You
can disable this *globally* in Rails, but that would break legacy integration
points I have to support.  Is there an elegant solution on either side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, much like my answer to your other question, in this case you can override parse() on your model. This is also generalizable in a model base class if you prefer.

```
parse: function(response)  {
  return response.model_name;
},
```

Edited to add code.

Comment: Parse is a one liner that takes the json object you get from the server and returns it. By default it's a no op. Just write one that returns the root object that you care about.